# rails 3 with mongodb assets precompile error:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

When I try to rake assets:precompile I get the following errors:

```
rake assets:precompile
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
execution expired
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/util/tcp_socket.rb:46:in `connect'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/util/tcp_socket.rb:46:in `block in connect'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/util/tcp_socket.rb:45:in `connect'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/util/tcp_socket.rb:40:in `initialize'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:582:in `new'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:582:in `check_is_master'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:468:in `connect'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:693:in `setup'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:155:in `initialize'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/util/uri_parser.rb:172:in `new'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/util/uri_parser.rb:172:in `connection'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:203:in `from_uri'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid/config/database.rb:86:in `master'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid/config/database.rb:19:in `configure'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid/config.rb:290:in `configure_databases'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid/config.rb:111:in `from_hash'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid/config.rb:126:in `block in load!'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid/config.rb:125:in `tap'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid/config.rb:125:in `load!'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid.rb:148:in `load!'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid/railtie.rb:84:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/jeanosorio/repos/blabloo/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:93:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p...]
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This is the result using the "--trace" commnad

```
rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
execution expired
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/util/tcp_socket.rb:46:in `connect'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/util/tcp_socket.rb:46:in `block in connect'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/util/tcp_socket.rb:45:in `connect'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/util/tcp_socket.rb:40:in `initialize'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:582:in `new'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:582:in `check_is_master'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:468:in `connect'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:693:in `setup'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:155:in `initialize'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/util/uri_parser.rb:172:in `new'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/util/uri_parser.rb:172:in `connection'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongo-1.9.2/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:203:in `from_uri'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid/config/database.rb:86:in `master'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid/config/database.rb:19:in `configure'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid/config.rb:290:in `configure_databases'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid/config.rb:111:in `from_hash'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid/config.rb:126:in `block in load!'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid/config.rb:125:in `tap'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid/config.rb:125:in `load!'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid.rb:148:in `load!'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid/railtie.rb:84:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/jeanosorio/repos/blabloo/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:93:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p...]
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:55:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `sh'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:82:in `ruby'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `ruby'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

I don't understand what is the problem here, because I make this before upload my files to the server, and now I get this errors but I didn't change anything.

Any suggestion would be appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: Try this command `bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile`

Comment: same error I don't understand what is happening

Comment: Looks like the application is not able to connect to mongoDB, Have you taken the basic steps to check if mongoDB is running and accessible ?

Comment: Robert, tell me more about how can I check this, because the app works great, but I don't know what exactly you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I delete all the files on my public/assets folder and then the

```
rake assets:precompile
```

works.

Thanks for your help